# What is the difference between Unit and ()Unit

Tags: scala

I have written two helloWorld functions, one with parentheses`()` and another, without.
If I invoke the one with parameters, either specifically with parameters or without, it works fine. The other one defined without parameters cries foul "`unit does not take parameters`". I am confused.

```
scala> def hWorld() = println("Hello World")
hWorld: ()Unit

scala> def hWorld = println("Hello World")
hWorld: Unit

scala> hWorld
Hello World

scala> hWorld()
<console>:10: error: Unit does not take parameters
              hWorld()
                    ^
scala> def hWorld2() = println("Hello World")
hWorld2: ()Unit

scala> hWorld2
Hello World

scala> hWorld2()
Hello World

scala>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`()Unit` is a method expecting empty parameter list, `Unit` is a method expecting no parameter list at all. The first is called nilary, while the second nullary.

[Nullary and Nilary Methods](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/nullary-and-nilary-methods/3756)